# Logging variables in a RapidMiner script

Tags: logging, rapidminer

I am new to RapidMiner and I'm learning how to execute scripts in a RapidMiner process. Normally when I'm writing say a Java program I like to `System.out.print` variables, this helps me with debugging. I am trying to achieve something similar  in RapidMiner.

I did some digging around it seems that I can log things to the Log panel by using `operator.log("Some text")`. I tried doing this (logging a simple string), but nothing is shown in my Log panel. I have two questions:

1. How do I "console log" variables in a RapidMiner script?
2. Is this the proper way I should be approaching debugging in RapidMiner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to make things show up in the log.

```
operator.logNote("some text");
```

It's probably the best way to debug.